# How do you say "on the air" for radio broadcasting

Tags: anglais

Very often, while listening to live DJs on radio stations I hear the phrase written as heard radifandit'r, my first thoughts were  that it means radio van d'etre or radio dans l'etre, so I concluded that it should mean something like radio on the air or on the air, meaning that the broadcast is live. The question is how do you say radio is on the air and how do I write radifandit'r in french??

I have added audio from the radio
https://soundcloud.com/scram-blers-63496289/rad2

Comment: You probably mean *en direct*. [*Diffusion en direct*](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#fr/en/diffusion%20en%20direct)

Comment: What radio stations? *Radifandit'r* doesn't sound like anything French, maybe *rediffusion*. Would you pronounce it the French way or the English one? "On the air" commonly translates to *à l'antenne*.

Comment: I added audio from the radio now

Comment: I was  just writing a comment to ask you for audio. If what you've been wondering is the thin repeated 5 or 6 times in the audio clip you link to, then you should hear "[David Vendetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Vendetta)"

Comment: So what does the audio say ?

Comment: I hear "dadi vends des poings, dadi vends des tas" which is quite meaningless...

Comment: Hi! There is absolutely no connection whatsoever between what it says and what you think it says. How to say "on the air" is a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends very much on your interlocutor: if you are a radio professional talking to a technician in a French radio station your could say
"On est live, coco".

If you want a more literary and old-fashioned expression you could say
"nous radiodiffusons en ce moment, mon ami".

Comment: The question was anything but clear but was edited in the meantime and now this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @un3hiv3r > Certainement. Il y a certainement des millions de réponses plus intéressantes que celle que j'aurais pu faire (et que je n'ai volontairement pas faite), mais si elles ne répondent pas à la question elles n'ont rien à faire sur SE.  A vrai dire c'est simplement la question qui n'a que peu de valeur pour SE.

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui je comprends, mais pourquoi ne pas alors modifier la question pour qu'elle traite exclusivement de « on the air » ou est-ce que cette question-là ne conviendrait pas ? On peut recycler, de toutes façons même en fermant la question elle reste « dans le système ». Je vois ça comme une forme d'aléa dont on peut peut-être tirer profit. Bof.